# Jquery mousenter and mouseleave should trigger only "active" .class

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

My issue is probably simple.
I currently have multiple buttons with the same class.
When you hover the button, I want a div (.blockButtonTips) to appear containing specific info related to the button.

My issue right now is that, when I hover one button, then the div appears successfully, however it appears for all of my buttons whereas I only want it to appear for the button being hovered.

I could add a unique identifier for each .blockButtonTips , but wondering if im actually able to target it without?

CODE

```
        //MOUSEOVER
        $(".blockButton").mouseenter(function() {
            //Passing on .class div to a function
            circleTextShow(".blockButtonTips");
        })
        //MOUSEOUT
        $(".blockButton").mouseleave(function() {
            timer= setTimeout(function() {
                //Passing on .class div to dis-appear to a function
                circleTextHide(".blockButtonTips");
            }, delay);
        });

    //Toggle div animation
    function circleTextShow(elementId) {
//make div appear animation code
    }

    function circleTextHide(elementId) {
//make div dis-appear code
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="blockButton">
    <div class="blockButtonTips">Text 1</div
</div>
<div class="blockButton">
    <div class="blockButtonTips">Text 2</div
</div>
<div class="blockButton">
    <div class="blockButtonTips">Text 3</div
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a reference to the div contained within the button to the circleTextShow / Hide functions.

```
//MOUSEOVER
        $(".blockButton").mouseenter(function() {
            //Passing on .class div to a function
            circleTextShow($(this).find('.blockButtonTips'));
        })
        //MOUSEOUT
        $(".blockButton").mouseleave(function() {
            var blockbutton = this;
            timer= setTimeout(function() {
                //Passing on .class div to dis-appear to a function
                circleTextHide($(blockbutton).find('.blockButtonTips'));
            }, delay);
        });
```

Then within the functions, you can reference the tips as so:

```
  //Toggle div animation
  function circleTextShow(element) {
     //make div appear animation code
     $(element).show();
  }

  function circleTextHide(element) {
     //make div dis-appear code     
     $(element).hide();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Rohrbs - thanks for the suggestion. Just tried this one out since it seemed pretty straightforward to me. Im not sure if im missing some point, but on my mouseleave, nothing happens (mouseover works). In my console log I can see on mouseover I get: "Object[div.blockButtonTips]" however looking on my mouseout I just get "Object[ ]

Comment: whoops! didn't notice that the hide call was in a `setTimeout()`. Edited the answer to capture the button in a variable, then use that variable from within the `setTimeou()` callback.

Comment: Thanks Rohrbs, I ended up using this solution. Many thanks for your responsiveness!

Answer (score 0):

send `$(this).find('.blockButtonTips')`  to the function and use that to show or hide

```
//MOUSEOVER
    $(".blockButton").mouseenter(function() {
        //Passing on .class div to a function
        circleTextShow($(this).find('.blockButtonTips'));
    })
    //MOUSEOUT
    $(".blockButton").mouseleave(function() {
        timer= setTimeout(function() {
            //Passing on .class div to dis-appear to a function
            circleTextHide($(this).find('.blockButtonTips'));
        }, delay);
    });

//Toggle div animation
function circleTextShow(element) {
  element.show()
}

function circleTextHide(elementId) {
    element.hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified bulletproof approach using
 `.on([delegated events])`,
 `Ternary operator (?:)`,
 `inversed-hover-intent` using the `data-*` attribute,
 and moving the `setTimeout` in your function

**gives this beautiful result:**

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ewusuq/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(".blockButton").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ) {
    var $tip = $('div', this); // Target the children .blockButtonTips 
    return e.type=="mouseenter" ? circleTextShow($tip) : circleTextHide($tip) ;
});

function circleTextShow( tip ) {
    clearTimeout( tip.data('wait') );
    tip.stop().fadeTo(500,1);
}

function circleTextHide( tip ) {
    tip.data('wait', setTimeout(function(){
       tip.stop().fadeTo(500,0);
    },300) );        
}
```